# history.push not working in wait or sync until button click

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I try to navigate page without refresh using "history.push()" It only work, when it clicked by human via button. It won't work programmatically . It is is only updating url but not navigating in browser.

```
//Index.js
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

//App.js
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact strict component={Login}/>
          <Route  path="/Homepage" exact strict component={Homepage}/>
      </Switch>

//History.js
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**Working fine**, When clicked directly using button.

```
//Working
  function btnClick(){ 
      history.push('/Homepage');
      }
```

**Not working**, When it is inside sync or wait function.

```
//Not Working
  const wait=ms=>new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); 
     wait(4*1000).then(() => { 
      history.push('/Homepage');
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the history on your Router correctly

```
<Router history={history} />
```

Comment: @TahaFarooqui I presume you are using `BrowserRouter` then and not a plain `Router`? If you want to use custom history then you need to switch these out.

Comment: I am using this one import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

Comment: @TahaFarooqui yeah so don't import `BrowserRouter`, just import `Router`. Also, FWIW you don't *have* to create your own history just to leverage `history.push`, this is generally the approach used if you are looking to sync browser history with your state management (e.g. Redux / Mobx etc).

Comment: Should I use useHistory from react-router-dom ?

Comment: @TahaFarooqui, useHistory would probably be worth looking at...

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Here is a discussion the authors have written about it...

https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/


> Heads up: The useHistory hook is a quick stopgap for a future hook that we are working on: useNavigate. ...{snipped}... We are providing useHistory for now to make the migration of existing code that uses the history API as painless as possible.